# Multiple text inputs wrapped in <div> within <td>

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, textinput

```
<td>
<form>
    <div class="pull-left" style="margin-top: 30px;">
        <input name="searchInput" tabindex="0" class="form-control input-sm" id="simple-field" style="min-width: 162px; max-width: 162px;" type="text" placeholder="Enter CI" value="" label="hid">
    </div>
<br>
<br>
    <div class="pull-left" style="margin-top: 30px;">
        <input name="searchInput" tabindex="0" class="margin-5-top form-control input-sm" id="simple-field" style="min-width: 162px; max-width: 162px;" type="text" placeholder="Enter CI" value="" label="hid">
    </div>
<br><br>
    <div class="pull-left" style="margin-top: 30px;">
        <input name="searchInput" tabindex="0" class="margin-5-top form-control input-sm" id="simple-field" style="min-width: 162px; max-width: 162px;" type="text" placeholder="Enter CI" value="" label="hid">
    </div>
<br><br>
</form>
<span style="color: rgb(174, 88, 86);">
</span>
</td>
```

which results in the following rendering in IE 11:
[image]
My question is how do I display this properly? the text forms are supposed to be stacked on top of one another, and not be arranged diagonally (red arrow) but rather horizontally.

Any assitance would be highly appreciated.
This works fine in Chrome btw.

Comment: you need to clear left too (if pull left floats left) or just remove the pull left class - I don't see why you need it

Comment: Do you even need the pull-left class. What is in the css and what happens if you remove the class?

Comment: I think pull-left was what was making my layout go awry. I removed it and not it works as expected! originally it was meant to help in orienting the inputs to the left, when i was using div layout but ever since I changed to table based layout, that definitely was unnecessary.

Comment: thank you for your assitance! pull-left is from react-bootstrap BTW if you were curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `pull-left` classes from all these `div`s  should  fix your problem (if you don't have any other code causing that behaviour which you didn't post)

(You might not need these `br` tags either)